# how to change text color in rails views

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

If status is "pending" show the "pending" on blue color. If status is "Accepted" show the "Accepted" in Green color. If status is "Rejected" show the Red color..

```
<% @applyleaves.each do |f| %>
<%= if f.status == 0
                 "Pending" 
       elsif f.status == 1
                 "Accepted"
       elsif f.status == 2
                 "Rejected"
       else
                 "Pending"
       end%>
</td>
```

Comment: Ok where i put enum status: { pending: 0, accepted: 1, rejected: 2 }

Comment: In your model. Add any comment you want to do right down the answer provided.

Comment: Your `erb tags` are not closed properly,

Comment: In question, you asked for enum status having string but holding numbers in code.

Answer (score 6):

If your status column (attribute) is an integer, you can use an enum, this way you have only 3 valid values for it:

```
# model
enum status: { pending: 0, accepted: 1, rejected: 2 }
```

Each key gives them a readable value. So in your view you can just create any html tag, in order to assign a class, which you previously defined with the color text you want:

```
<span class="<%= "#{f.status.downcase}_status" %>">
  <%= f.status.capitalize %>
</span>
```

The CSS isn't more than this:

```
<style>
  .pending_status {
   color: blue;
  }
  .accepted_status {
   color: green;
  }
  .rejected_status {
   color: red;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: How do you directly invoke `enum` status as `f.status.capitalize` if it holds hash?

Comment: My friend, if `f` is a (poor named) AR object, its enum status is accessible as it's named. No matter if the attribute is represented as a Hash by Rails.